# How to add fs module to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do a chrome extension and I need to get data from the website and write it to a CSV file. For this I import fs but it says cannot use import statements outside a module.

```
import {fs} from "fs";
```

That's the code I write but it's not working. How can I add a module to the chrome extension?

Is there any workaround or another way to import?

Comment: `fs` is a Node.js module. Browsers don't provide this module.

Answer (score -1):

The file system is not available from browser in any way.